# How to write jquery toggle function for icon(which is generated from css) in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario,where I need to collapse the footer in mobile device,I tried with css media queries and jquery toggle function.But,I need to use angularjs.I tried it with using ng-show/ng-hide.But here,the '+' or '-' is getting from css.So, how I need to give click action for those signs.Click function must be given dynamically.

Script:

```
$( ".widget h2" ).click(
    function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    }
);
```

I need above code in angularjs.

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ktQNuw84ITbxiG4PM1r3?p=preview)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.resize` event

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($windowWidth <= 479) {
        $('.widget').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Here is your updated [plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/v8A8McEgYsJDVO1j)

More improved version:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    CheckWindowWidth();
});
$('.widget h2').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .toggleClass('active');
});

function CheckWindowWidth() {
    $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($windowWidth <= 479) {
        $('.widget').addClass('active');
    }
}
CheckWindowWidth();
```

**Edit**:
As per angular version you can use this

In your html change

```
<div class="col-md-5 widget" ng-class="{'active': setSignInData }">
                <h2 ng-click="setSignInData = !setSignInData">sign in data</h2>
                <article class="widget_content">
                    <ul ng-class="autoScroll?'widget':'active widget'">
                        <li>Get a quote</li>
                        <li>Send quote</li>

                 </ul>
                 </article>
            </div>
```

In your controller

```
 $scope.setSignInData = false;
```

This will change the scope variable and toggle active class

Comment: I need toggle function using ng-click.

Comment: @pbsbr please update your plunkr to support angularjs, and I have edited my answer with more precise solution.

Comment: Sorry I need with angularjs(toggle function)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `ng-class` to `toggle css` classes based on your conditions.
I would personally suggest to avoid using jquery in angularjs projects.
For ways on how you can use the `ng-class`,

you can go through the following [blog](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)